# PowerShell [wmiclass] Win32_Process.Create() then wait for batch file to complete

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, sql-agent-job, get-wmiobject

I have scheduled a SQLserver agent job that execute a PowerShell script that calls a batch process to start. However, when PowerShell is executed, it did not wait for the batch file to complete before moving to the next job step. What can I do to make it "wait" for the batch file to complete before moving on?

this is the command:

```
  ([WMICLASS]"\\SERVER\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process").Create("cmd.exe /c E:\BatchFiles\First_Batch_File.bat")
```

Comment: You've provided us with a single working line from a powershell script, this calls a batch file whose contents we have been excluded from and this runs as a SQL server agent job scheduled by a method also not provided. Let me suggest that a solution could go hand in hand with further pertinent information from yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Create` method will return the `ProcessId` of the process it creates. You can check if that process has terminated with `Get-Process`

```
$process = ([WMICLASS]"\\SERVER\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process").Create("cmd.exe /c E:\BatchFiles\First_Batch_File.bat")
while ((Get-Process -Id $process.ProcessId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -ne $null) {
    write-host "waiting"
    sleep 2
}
```

Comment: Paths with spaces will not work this way. Here you need to add escaped double quotes at $batFilePath:
         $process = ([WMICLASS]"\\$MashineName\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process").Create("cmd.exe /c `"$batFilePath`"")

Comment: @Garric The path in the question did not have spaces.